# Using "Find" Command in tandem with "if" "and" statements

Tags: bash, find

I need to search and find sub-directories that contain a certain file, however if they contain this certain file + this other file, I do not want them to be listed.

The statement looks something like this:

1. Find the directories that contain the file "password.old"
2. If the directory contains "password.old" and "webvirtual" don't list them
3. If the directory ONLY contains "password.old" and does not contain "webvirtual" then output directory path to > OLD.TXT file

This is what I have thus far, is this totally wrong? It seems to be working correctly, but I'm fairly new to bash scripting and just wanted to make sure I'm not missing something... or maybe there's a better way to handle this?

```
#!/bin/sh
if FILE=$(find ./ -path OLD/ -prune -o -name "password.old") && FILE=$(find ./ -path OLD/ -prune -o -name "webvirtual*")
then
printf %"s\n" $FILE > Not_Old_Ones.txt
fi
if FILE=$(find ./ -path OLD/ -prune -o -name "password.old") && FILE=$(find ./ -path OLD/ -prune -o ! -name "webvirtual*")
then
printf %"s\n" $FILE > Old_Ones.txt
fi
```

Comment: Or should I be using the `[` and `]` for true/false checks? How would I wrap the find command in the boolean true/false check and apply it to the variable `FILE` though so I can output it to a file?

Comment: Where should OLD.txt be located ? In that same directory ?

Comment: Yeah where the script is ideally, or anywhere really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly lengthy , but working solution, which should work for cases where `-execdir` is not available:

```
$ tree
.
├── dir_one
│   ├── password.old
│   └── webvirtual
└── dir_two
    └── password.old
$ find . -iname "*password.old" -exec dirname "{}" \; 2>/dev/null | while IFS= read -r directory; do
> [ -e "$directory"/webvirtual ] && continue || echo "$directory"
> done
./dir_two
```

Thus , all you need to do now, it add `> OLD.txt` at the end of the `done` statement to redirect output to file

In case the `dirname` command is not available, you can use the following script with directory as argument.

```
#!/bin/sh

find "$1" -type f -iname "*password.old"  -printf "%h\n" |
while IFS= read -r directory;
do
    [ -e "$directory"/webvirtual ] && continue || echo "$directory"
done
```

For example:

```
$ ./find_missing_webvirtual.sh ./TESTDIR/                                                                                
./TESTDIR/dir_two
```

Comment: Whoa, is the structure you're listing actually part of the script or is that just for a users sake to see what the script is doing? I've never seen something of the sort before. First time.

Comment: @PietroAretino `tree` is a separate command, not part of script. It's available pretty much on most Linux distros with GNU utilities.  And yes, that's just for user's sake to visualize how the simple example of directories is organized

Comment: I'm surmising I must initialize `$directory`, as of right now the script gives me a blank file when I tried running it. However even when I give it `directory='/var/accounts/'` or `directory='./'` I am still getting a blank file. The script seems to run with no errors however. Hmm. Much appreciated none-the-less kind sir or madam.

Comment: @PietroAretino  No, the variable `$directory` shouldn't be initialized. You could do `find /var/accounts/` , but originally the script is intended to be run from the directory itself, so `cd /var/accounts` and then run. Also, you indicated you have an older server. Do you have the `dirname` command there ? It might be part of the issue. I'll edit my answer for alternative version.

Comment: Yes dirname command seems to be working. It's running CentOS 4.9. Probably why I'm having so many difficulties. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Thank you Serg. The last one did the trick. I love this site, because now I can dissect your code and better understand how and why you wrote the script as you did. Regardless, that worked flawlessly. All I needed to do was add the wildcard to the end of webvirtual for it to work perfectly. Once again. Extremely appreciative of your your time and @Stephane aswell.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do:

```
find . -path ./OLD -prune -o -name password.old \
  ! -execdir [ -e webvirtual ] \; -printf '%h\n'
```

`-execdir` is found in GNU `find` (since 4.2.12 (2005)), `sfind` and most BSDs (where it comes from). `-printf` is GNU-specific. You can replace it with `-execdir pwd \;` for other `find` implementations.

If `-execdir` is not available:

```
find . -path ./OLD -prune -o -name password.old -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    dir=${file%/*}
    [ -e "$dir/webvirtual" ] || printf "%s\n" "$dir"
  done' sh {} +
```

The above would be POSIX. On Solaris 10 and older, be sure to use the standard `sh` in `/usr/xpg4/bin`, not the one in `/bin`.

Comment: Unfortunately the server I'm running this on contains an older version of `find` and does not understand `-execdir`. At least I believe that is what it is telling me. I get the error: _find: invalid predicate '-execdir'_